# Int64.add等がUnbound valueになる

Tags: ocaml

[`Int64`](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Int64.html)モジュールの`add`, `sub`, `mul`, `div`といった名前が`Unbound value`になってしまうのですが、どうすれば使えるようになるでしょうか。

```
utop # Int64.add;;
Error: Unbound value Int64.add
```

ちなみに

- `Int64.zero`, `Int64.rem`などは見えている
- `Int32`でも同じ

という状況です。

OCamlのバージョンは4.02.3です。

**追記**
`utop`で`module type S = module type of Int64;;`とした結果、四則演算の`add`,`sub`,`mul`,`div`は無いようです。

- `module Map`>`module Tree`に`val add : 'a t -> key:int64 -> data:'a -> 'a t`
- `module Set`>`module Tree`に`val add : t -> int64 -> t`
- `module Table`に`` val add : 'b t -> key:key -> data:'b -> [ `Duplicate | `Ok ] ``

がそれぞれ２回ずつ現れました。

Comment: `module type S = module type of Int64;;` で `add` とか出ますか

Comment: @camlspotter コメントありがとうございます。実行結果を本文に追記しました。

Comment: Module type に `add` 等がないということは、単にそういうものがない `Int64` という名前のモジュールを使っているということですね。デフォルトの OCaml ではそんなことはないはずなので、何か特殊なライブラリを使っているのではないでしょうか。見るからに Core か Base っぽいのでその `Int64` は標準の `Int64` じゃないと思います。

Comment: おっしゃるとおりでCoreを使っています。今回も`open Core.Std`していました。自分が使っていたのはhttps://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/111.17.00/doc/core/#Std.Int64ということですね。ところで、一旦`open Core.Std`するとデフォルトの`Int64`にはアクセスできないのでしょうか？

Comment: オリジナルのモジュール `Xxx` は確か `Caml.Xxx` とかからアクセスできたと思いますが、確かめていません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。`Caml.Int64.add`でアクセスできることを確認しました。